# How to show alert once after installing the app in ios device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

How to show an alert only once at the start of an application after installing the application on device or on simulator until I delete it from my device. Is it possible tell me..

Comment: NSUserDefaults . here. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/

Comment: what is the default value for boolean while using NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
   //first launch
   //show your alert
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else
{
    // app already launched
}
```

Comment: AppDelegate>applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: Hi.. Its not working... while switch off and then switch on the device then after i opened my app it shows me the alert...

Comment: do 
    [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

after you set the bool

Comment: Thanks for your response...before checking the condition default value for HasLaunchedOnce is false or not

Comment: It is not saved in default values before checking, SO how the key will exist previously..?

Comment: I am just asking Is it has any default value or not..? Ok now my doubt was clarified..I set HasLaunchedOnce to false before checking the condition... Is it fine...

Comment: Nikitha I tried it many times on the device..after doing sychronization but Its not working.. It again shows me the alert after switch on the device..

Comment: Its working fine...                                                 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"] == NO) {
   //first launch
   //show your alert
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES               forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];                                   [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else
{
    // app already launched
}