# Popup User Agreement Display in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I'm trying to implement a code into Swift where a user is given a popup alert upon initial launch of the app.  And I would prefer not to have it popup again each time the app is re-launched.  I'm thinking using UIAlert in ViewDidLoad() but don't know the code to determine if the app has been launched more than once.  Would appreciate any input and code examples.  Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show alert once after installing the app in ios device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495747/how-to-show-alert-once-after-installing-the-app-in-ios-device)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NSUserDefault` storage to do this

```
let firstLaunchKey = "firstLaunch"
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(firstLaunchKey) == nil{
    // show your alert and then set firstLauch key
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: firstLaunchKey)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found this elsewhere. Putting it into `AppDelegate.swift`

```
    let AlertOnce = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if(!changeAlert.boolForKey("oneTimeAlert")){
        var alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Welcome"
        alert.message = "welcome message"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.delegate = self
        alert.show()
        AlertOnce.setBool(true , forKey: "oneTimeAlert")
        AlertOnce.synchronize()
    }
```